# How to select one row, and then select the rest

Tags: mysql, database, random, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am trying to achieve the following:

table

```
    featured    product
row1    0       product1
row2    0       product2
row3    1       product3
row4    1       product4
row5    0       product5
row6    1       product6
```

output (the top row is always featured)

```
row4    1       product4
rowRandom
rowRandom
rowRandom
rowRandom
rowRandom
```

In the "output" the top row is always featured. The other rows are random (minus the featured row).

Can I do this with mySQL or should I do it with php?

Thanks and regards,

Neil.

Comment: So the top row should a *randomly chosen* record having `featured = 1`, or a specific record?

Comment: why `row4    1       product4` and not `row3    1       product3` or `row6    1       product6` for the top row,  those are also featured ?  to add to @GMB 's comment

Comment: @RaymondNijland That was just my example output. It could be any of the rows where `featured = 1`.

Comment: @GMB Yes. Correct.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First select randomly a featured row and also add a new column which will be used for the sorting and use `UNION ALL` for the rest of the rows.
Finally `group by featured, product` to remove the duplicate of the 1st row:

```
select t.featured, t.product 
from (
  select f.*, 0 ordercol from (
    select * from tablename
    where featured 
    order by rand()
    limit 1
  ) f
  union all
  select *, 1 from tablename
) t
group by t.featured, t.product 
order by min(t.ordercol), rand()
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/odnWrX7pf3tmzU2cerL6jZ/1).
Results (random):

```
| featured | product  |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | product4 |
| 0        | product1 |
| 1        | product3 |
| 0        | product5 |
| 1        | product6 |
| 0        | product2 |
```

Comment: why not use `UNION` instead ? Then you don't need that `GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ...` to unduplicate or do i mis something very obvious now??

Comment: Because there is a new column `ordercol` in the resultset and union will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this in a single scan with `row_number()` and `rand()`:

```
select 
    product, 
    featured
from tablename
order by 
    case 
        when 
            featured = 1 
            and row_number() over(partition by featured order by rand()) = 1
        then 0
        else 1
    end,
    rand()
```

The `order by` clause will randomly pick a record with `featured = 1` and put it in first position, and then display the other records, in a random order.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee3fa9182c8e28999f433f0a7ec480b3)**:

Run #1:

```
product  | featured
:------- | -------:
product4 |        1
product6 |        1
product1 |        0
product5 |        0
product2 |        0
product3 |        1
```

Run #2:

```
product  | featured
:------- | -------:
product3 |        1
product2 |        0
product1 |        0
product6 |        1
product4 |        1
product5 |        0
```